# html5lib not recognised in docker container

Tags: python, docker

I am using html5lib as a parser for BeautifulSoup in a project. The code is working fine locally, but in a production environment I am getting the `FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?` error.

this is the line of code where it is being called:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
```

I am deploying using docker, when I exec into the container and run pip list html5lib is installed correctly, I also tried reinstalling within the container.

here is the requirements.txt to show it is being installed properly:

```
APScheduler==3.10.1
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
fastapi==0.95.2
uvicorn==0.22.0
pendulum==2.1.2
pydantic==1.10.7
pymongo==4.3.3
python-dotenv==1.0.0
redis==4.5.5
Requests==2.31.0
sentry_sdk==1.23.1
zeep==4.2.1
html5lib==1.1
```

here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.15

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /app/requirements.txt

ENV TZ=UTC

COPY . /app

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080", "--proxy-headers"]
```

Any ideas on why it wouldn't be working?

The image is built and pushed to docker hub with this GitHub action:

```
name: Push to Docker Hub

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build and push image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: chrisg06/naips-api:latest
```

I am then Using docker-compose to start it along with a few other dependancies like mongodb and redis.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you've described. Please included a complete set of steps that reproduces this behavior, including how you are building the image and how you are running the image.

Comment: @larsks edited to include workflow that is building the image.

Comment: Have you made sure that you're actually using the latest image? Try running `docker compose pull`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `html.parser` instead of `html5lib` (`BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`).

But, if there is a specific advantage in using `html5lib` then the following steps should solve your problem.

1. Remove the upgrade flag (`--upgrade`) from your Dockerfile.
2. Update your packages:

   - `pip install -U beautifulsoup4`
   - `pip install -U html5lib`
   - `pip install -U lxml`
3. Update the `requirements.txt` file:

   - `pip freeze > requirements.txt`